# Are there any "fake" French words used in English?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, french

Are there any "fake" French words used in English?  By "fake French" I mean words that are of French origin but are not actually correct French. This could happen if the word changes as it becomes adopted by English speakers. "Fake" may not be the best term for this -- if anyone can think of something better, please let me know. I mean French-derived terms that have evolved to the point of no longer being common-usage French.

Some examples of the reverse, i.e. "fake English" words used in French:

- [relooking](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/relooking), which means makeover -- this is derived from the English word "look" but "relooking" is not used by English speakers
- [happy end](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/happy_end) -- minor difference, but in the US at least we say "happy ending" and not "happy end"
- [brushing](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brushing) -- blow-drying your hair is called "un brushing", clearly derived from English, but if you announce "I'm going to get a brushing today" nobody will understand you
- [afterwork](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/afterwork) -- I'm not certain here, but I think "an afterwork" is extremely rare in English. In French, however, "un afterwork" is common and refers to meeting up after work, e.g. at a bar
- [smoking](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/smoking) -- in French, "un smoking" is a fancy dinner jacket, which comes from the English "smoking jacket" -- but you can't say "I'm going to wear a smoking tonight" in English, at least not in the US
- Inspired by Dan's comment: [footing](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/footing) means a jog; you can't say "I'm going on a footing" in English, and the French wiktionary article explicitly states that this is a "faux anglicisme"
- Found after following links on wiktionary: un [lifting](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lifting) means a facelift; it's another English-derived French word that was never actually used by English speakers

The word "fake" in my title might be confusing -- I'm not looking for words that are pronounced with fake French accents, but rather for French-derived words that have evolved to the point of no longer being common-usage French (or that were never used in French to begin with, the way the French word footing was never used in English).

---

This question was closed for being too broad; this edit is an attempt to narrow it down.

I'm looking specifically for words that (a) are used in English; (b) are derived from French; but (c) would not make sense to a French speaker, either because the word was never used in French in the first place, or because the French and English versions of the word have drifted extremely far apart.

An example of the reverse is "un footing" in French: "a footing" is complete nonsense in English, and it would be hard to even guess what it means.

Some examples of words that aren't what I'm looking for:

- The US usage of entrée doesn't really satisfy criterion (c) above: sure, the meanings have diverged a little bit, but barely.
- Same comment as above for the US usage of petite -- it's still understandable to a French speaker.

I'm particularly interested in French-derived words that were never used in French, the way "footing" and "relooking" were never used in English.

Comment: You are asking for something which has a name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend. Searching for this should find some good examples (although you probably will have to manually sort for those in the correct direction)

Comment: Are you looking for *false cognates*? Something like these lists? http://www.fluentu.com/french/blog/faux-amis-french-false-friends-cognates/ http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/French/Vocabulary/French-English-False_friends.html http://www.thelocal.fr/20140814/false-friends-france-english http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/MED-Magazine/July2003/09-french-english-false-friends.htm

Comment: @rumtscho This isn't about false friends. False friends are words that look like cognates but are not, deceptively so to a learning speaker. What this question is about are words borrowed from another language and given a meaning that seems (to a native speaker of the borrowing language) to have a proper derived meaning, but are seen by a native speaker of the borrowed-from language to be alien.

Comment: Interesting, Afterwork is used the same way in Swedish as in French. Pretty funny how an English word is used a certain way internationally but not in actual English-speaking countries.

Comment: @Tobberoth In Czech, both "happyend" and "smoking" are used this way too. Interesting indeed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie that's a good way of putting it, especially the bit about feeling alien to a native speaker of the borrowed-from language

Comment: Cool question! It got both my up- & reopen-vote earlier so I have nothing more to add except the following off-topic comment:  Another curious subset of French-to-English words would include the ones that, although retaining their basic meaning in both languages, have made it back to France as French nouns in forms that look and sound suspiciously like English gerunds/present participles (e.g., [le]‘camping/dancing/parking’=‘campground/dance hall/parking lot’).

Comment: @PapaPoule thank you, I'm glad you find it interesting.  I was surprised (and amused) by the nastiness of a certain commenter who had voted to close (and has since deleted his comment); it's nice to hear from the other side.

Comment: The question is interesting. But it requires specific expertise in French to validate if a word is correct French. As answers showed, that expertise is lacking (as French is not the topic here) and many native French speakers had to suggest edits to many answers which otherwise would have been misleading if not entirely false/incorrect. Such a question can never be a proper fit for either En/Fr site. Finally "fake French" is unbecoming of a title and not one serious enthusiast could edit that to _loan/mock words with no active use in Fr_. This should have remained closed imho. Thanks.

Comment: I've read in a couple of books by some British authors, "met/meet a happy end."

Comment: The answer needs to have a certain _je ne sais quoi_.

Comment: Also, shampoing!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requests a list. And if 'fake French' means 'not in the English lexis', it's off-topic for a second reason.

Comment: Do you mean like how people in English say "no problemo" as if that's Spanish for "no problem" when it's not really Spanish at all? Because in Spanish there's no word "problemo" as the word for "problem" is "problema," so were it real Spanish, it'd be "no problema," or more often "no hay problema," but never "no problemo" since, while it's made to sound like Spanish, it's not really.

Comment: ' blow-drying your hair is called "unbrushing" ' - makes sense - oh wait.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, there's even two sections for different types of these in the Wikipedia article about French phrases used in English ("List of French expressions in English"):

- [Not used as such in French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_expressions_in_English#Not_used_as_such_in_French)
- [Found only in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_expressions_in_English#Found_only_in_English)

I remember reading before that [*nom de plume*](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/10/nom-de-plume.html) is not idiomatic in French, where instead they use *nom de guerre*. However, it appears that *nom de plume* now exists in French as well (thanks to [Basj](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300015/are-there-any-fake-french-words-used-in-english/300022?noredirect=1#comment675543_300022) for the correction), possibly due to influence from the English term.

Another funny one I vaguely remembered reading about is [*giclée*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gicl%C3%A9e), a neologism coined to make art printed using an inkjet printer sound fancier, but that has unfortunate connotations of ejaculation in French (it literally refers to a "spurt" or "squirt").

Comment: Ye-es... although a lot of these have pretty much the same meaning in English as in French...

Comment: @Dan: which ones? I linked to the two sections of the article that are supposed to list only words with different meanings in French and English. Above these sections, there's a list of words with more or less the same meaning. I linked to the whole article just for completeness.

Comment: The 'Found only in English' list includes many that are very close to the French root (e.g. slightly mispelt).

Comment: The 'Not used as such in French' likewise is often on the nit-picking side of interesting.  I am finding it hard, not being bilingual, working out which words from French (assuming you can spot them!) have actually morphed into something distinct.

Comment: So what do _they_ call _their_ demi-monde?

Comment: I agree with @Dan that many of the words "Found only in English" according to the wikipedia list are not actually found only in English.  For example, https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/demi-monde

Comment: @Adrian: it doesn't work as a list of words without comment, but each word in the Wikipedia article does have a brief description of the situation; for *demi-monde* it acknowledges that it has been used in French, but says it "fell out of use in the French language in the 19th century." (Though personally, I think it's mostly fallen out of use in English as well by now.)

Comment: @sumelic I'm pretty sure https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aide_de_camp would be understood by most French speakers

Comment: @Adrian: yeah, and the Wikipedia article explicitly says "It exists in French too but is written aide de camp (without any hyphens)." I didn't write the list, and I'm not claiming it's entirely accurate in its classification, I just think it seems like a good place to start (and as long as you read the notes, I haven't found any information that is contradicted by other sources). Do you want me to go and extract the best examples of words that actually are not used in any form in French with anything like their English meaning?

Comment: @sumelic no, you don't need to do that -- your answer provides what I was looking for, and overall those lists are excellent.  I just agree with Dan that a few of the words have essentially the same meaning in French and English.

Comment: I don't understand why entrée is in the english-only section. Likewise, the term "negligé" is sometimes used in the same sense in french.

Comment: *Nom de plume* **is** idiomatic in French (I'm French), but I never heard *nom de guerre* (in such a context) in my whole life.

Comment: @njzk: the article is saying that "negligée" is used in English for the same sense as "negligé" in French, so they're spelled differently. Is "entrée" used to mean "main course" in French? That's how it's mainly used in American English.

Comment: @Basj: thanks, that is valuable information as I'm not French. I guess "nom de plume" has become the usual term in French as well nowadays. I'll  correct what I wrote.

Comment: @sumelic thanks, I didn't notice the final "e". No, entrée is always the first dish, never the main course in French. Apparently that's still the case in UK English as well, and only in American English did the meaning evolved this way.

Comment: @sumelic Nom de plume means a pseudonym used by an author, nom de guerre is a pseudonym used in war (famous WWII examples being General Leclerc and Colonel Roland)

Comment: The links don't include *casserole*, which has become a pet peeve of mine. In French it only refers to a certain kind of cooking ustensil (cylindrical, deep, and usually made of metal).

Answer (score 50):

"Double entendre" is a fake term made of two real French words which is only understood by English speakers and has no real meaning in French:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre#Etymology

Comment: great example!!

Comment: Excellent example, about as "fake" as the French word footing

Comment: Exactly the example I would have chosen.

Comment: I had no idea the 'double' came from French too.

Comment: @Luke French borrowings are something like 60% or 70% of the English lexicon.

Comment: Nope, the estimates I've seen are around 30%.

Comment: More accurate to say that English borrows heavily from Romance languages in general. It certainly is not a particularly *unique genre*, you might say.

Comment: Interesting. So exactly what ***do*** they call a term such as "Manoeuvre De Derrière" in French if not a *double entendre*? It is claimed that Napoleon used this strategy in battle no less than 30 times between 1796 and 1815, and even more often with Josephine.

Comment: @Luke It depends on how you count and what corpus you use.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_French_origin) claims 45% but excludes all derivations ("strait," "jacket," and "joy," but not "joyful" or "straitjacket").  Regardless of how you count it's a very large percentage (and it gets still larger if you count Latinate words received by way of French, etc., etc.).  In short, "nope" is a little too simple.

Comment: @Casey: The excludes words are the words excluded from the list, not excluded from counts. Either way, the only research referenced on wikipedia is the Finkenstaedt and Williams and they took - if I understand it correctly - the top 80.000 words and then French ended up with 29% which is in line with Luke's 'nope'.

Comment: @DavidMulder Well, the question of how many of the most used 80,000 words and how much of the "lexicon," including rarely-used, specialist, etc., terms are two rather different issues which is why I feel it's too facile to simply call a number "wrong" without defining the terms of the discussion.  Either way the number of French-origin words is quite significant.

Comment: @Casey If you know about better research, feel free to bring it up. Right now all actually referenced research backs up the 30% figure and totally justifies Luke's remark. I have heard percentages up to 50% float around, but your '60 or 70%' was high enough that calling it simply 'wrong' (which nobody did) seems quite fair.

Comment: It was my understanding that "double entendre" was a loan phrase dating from Anglo-Norman period. So it would've been valid French in some regional dialect of France (Normandy?) or in some previous era.

Comment: So does "Triple Entente" fall in the same category?  From *Double Entendre* to *Triple Entente*!  Le huh huh huh!

Comment: @ziggurism "Double entendre" cannot be genuine French being grammatically incorrect whatever the dialect. A correct expression was "Double entendement" which is attested too in middle English. e.g. **For many mane spekes in double entendement 
In poysees & sophsyms mene full myche hydes; 
The mysty wordes oute es wente 
The brighte worde in þe brest habydes.** (source: http://merg.soc.srcf.net/journal/08cambridge/byrne.php )

Answer (score 17):

One French word which has (perhaps amusingly) taken on a [dramatically new meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=douche) in English (esp. US) is [**douche**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/douche):

> shower

Comment: Wow, you're the only one who remembered it! It's amazing how the most obvious stuff is often overlooked.

Answer (score 15):

Entrée actually means appetizer in French. the French use "plat principal" ou "plat de resistance" for entrée.

Comment: This is also a difference between BrE and AmE. Only in North American usage does "entree" mean main course; in most other English-speaking areas, it retains the original French meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MikeHarris! I was thinking, "But _entrée_ means _appetiser_ in English as well!"

Comment: I have found this very confusing in the USA.  *Where are the main dishes?!*

Comment: @gerrit well, but will you look at *size* of these horsd’œuvres!

Answer (score 15):

- **Patron**

First time I traveled to the US, I was quite puzzled by a "**Patron Parking Only**" sign outside a restaurant.

**Patron** evolved differently with one of it English meaning being **customer** while in French ***patron*** main acception is colloquial for **manager**, i.e. translates to **boss**.

I somewhat hesitated to risk parking my car to a space I thought was reserved for the manager use...

It is quite amusing to see that what used to be the Latin ***patronus*** has slightly evolved in English to finally mean **client**, while the latter precisely comes from the Latin ***clientes*** which was the exact antonym of ***patronus***.

- **Verge**

Another puzzling word I saw in the UK : some road signs show "**Soft verge, keep off**" or "Soft verge for two miles". That would be "Soft shoulder" in the US and *Accotements non stabilisés*" in French. "**Verge**" originally meant rod / wand in both French and English but the meanings highly diverged as nowadays, in French, the word is almost exclusively used as a non slang, medical term for **penis** / **phallus**.

- **Grapes**

As already answered by BlokeDownThePub **raisins** are French ***raisins secs*** but it happens also that **Grapes**, which comes from the French ***Grappe*** ( = **cluster/bunch**) are French ***raisins***.
That means "**a cluster of grapes**" translates to ***une grappe de raisin***.

- **Pet pourri**

Once in the New Jersey, I saw a store likely selling pet stuff that was named **Pet pourri**, obviously a pun with "**pet**" and "**pot pourri**". Their authors were obviously unaware the pun was much more funny in French. While **Pot-pourri** means, I guess like in English, a mixture of dried flowers, **Pet pourri** means **Rotten fart** ...

I just found there are several businesses using that name in the US: a [similar shop still in NJ](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pet-Pourri/214490781910102), a [web site](http://petpourri.com/shop/), a [grooming](http://www.petpourriegrooming.com/) place in FL and even a [nick name](https://plus.google.com/100391412621597450052/posts).

- **Demand**

Not exactly a fake word but there is a serious difference in meaning with the French ***demande*** that sometimes lead to issues. A "**demand**" is an ***exigeance*** in French while the French ***demande*** is just a (polite) request. I have seen English speaking pissed off by what they thought was an arrogant behavior when unaware Frenchmen were "demanding" something while they really just ask for it.

- **Preservatives**

English **preservatives** are French ***conservateurs*** while French ***Preservatifs*** are English **Condoms**...

- **Reservoir**

English **reservoirs** are French ***lacs de retenue/lacs artificiels***  (it used to be *réservoir* too but that meaning has been lost in current French). French ***Réservoir*** is mostly used to express what is in English a **Fuel (or any liquid) tank**.

- **Fabric** / **Tissue**

English **fabric** is French ***tissu*** while French ***fabrique*** is English **factory**. English **tissue** is mostly used to name what French call ***mouchoir en papier*** (Kleenex® too).

- **Concierge**

English **concierges** will eventually be named ***concierges*** too but currently, most French people are reluctant to call them that way because traditionally French ***concierges***, essentially located in the ground floor of Paris area buildings, are what is called in English **janitors/caretakers**. Nowadays, these old style ***concierges*** have mostly disappeared though.

Comment: I have never understood this one. How did patron in AmE get to mean "customer" rather than "boss"?

Comment: @Christine: A patron is one who provides you with the money to continue doing what you do. That describes both a [recurring] customer in relation to the business as such, and a boss in relation to an employee.

Comment: @Christine: To complement Henning's precise explanation, just think about the different meanings of the English verb “to patronise” (or “-ize”).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Patron cames from the Latin *Patronus*, derived from *Pater* (father), litteraly "almost father", meaning either the defender (~ lawyer) or protector (a patrician was protecting multiple plebeians who, in return, were giving a financial compensation to the *Patronus*). These plebeians were called *Clientes* which gave "client" in both French and English. Unlike most and probably all other languages that inherited both of these roots, only English has managed to transform the patron into a client, while these words were exact antonyms in Latin.

Comment: I was just thinking of the French word _patron_ and the American English word _patron_. English _patron_ comes from French _patron_, not from _patronize_. If I'm wrong here, I apologize. Neither English nor French is my native language, though I'm fluent in both.

Comment: @jlliagre I mean, a customer is similar enough to a patron if you're an artist or something like that.  Also both words retain their original senses when we're talking about, for instance, patron and client states.

Comment: If "the customer is always right", who's the boss?

Comment: @PeterShor Indeed, in French we say too *Le client est roi* (The customer is king). Note that I would even less park my car in a "boss only" labeled space.

Answer (score 13):

In BrE, as well as in French, "à la mode" means "fashionable". However, in AmE, it means "with a scoop of icecream".

Similarly, interpretations of entrée differ radically, meaning "starter" in BrE, and "main course" in AmE, and "entrance" in French.

Comment: Entrée also means starter (in the food sense) in France.

Comment: A small typo, that's *à la mode*, not *á la mode*.

Comment: @jilliagre Darn it! My machine is even *set up to autocorrect it* if I'd just not put the accent there in the first place.

Comment: I would argue that "with a scoop of ice cream" is just the fashionable way to eat a slice of pie. (And honestly, can you blame us?)

Answer (score 11):

***Parley*** - To treat, discuss terms; esp. to hold a parley (with an enemy or opponent), to come to parley. (OED)

This is a French word that has a different English meaning.

Comment: That's a good one!

Comment: Well if we're going to open it up to words that are derived from French but have since drifted in meeting in one language or the other we're going to go way beyond the scope of a single answer here, I think (by that standard I guess "chef" counts, for instance, but do you really think of that as a "French word?").

Comment: @Casey - doesn't 'chef' mean pretty much the same thing in English and French.  The idea here, I think, is a word clearly from French, but with a sense as far away as possible from the French usage. I'm finding it  surprisingly hard to come up with good examples!

Comment: @Dan [No](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chef/15043?q=chef#14910), it means "leader."  "Chief" comes from the Old French version of the same word.

Comment: I think the example of "double entrendre" is a good one; there's one that we *think* of as French -- it's not unusual to see it in italics and many people insist on pronouncing it with a French accent, despite it being nonsense ("double to mean") in French.  But we have very many French-origin words that no one would do that with because their foreignness is no longer really felt.

Comment: @Casey You mean “double to hear”. Ironically, though it's not proper French, it's still *sensical* in French.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, it has more than one meaning, and I picked "mean" or "intend" but I guess maybe that's a stretch.  "Understand" is maybe more likely.  You could see [here](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/entendre/29878?q=entendre#29778) for a number of other possibilities.

Comment: @Casey Ah! As an English speaker of French, only the more common “hearing” meaning ever occurred to me. The rest never would have occurred to me to take as the meaning of the word in this phrase. That said, I can see how the other meanings could make some sense, now that you point them out. They all nicely end up with "double intentions" or somesuch as their meaning, too.

Comment: @Casey - clearly *chef* in French is more like 'chief' or 'head' in English.  But the English use of 'chef' is closely, unambiguously and easily understood from the French *chef de cuisine*.  The OP is seeking French words used in English whose English meaning would not easily be understood by a French speaker.

Comment: Pintel: "Parley? Damn to the depths whatever man that thought up parley!" Jack: "That would be the French."

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - nice, but ... d'you not think Jack is showing off his erudition (i.e. that parley derives from parlez).  The point is that not everyone gets the connection - least of all the French, because parley doesn't mean parlez!

Comment: @Dan Well, yeah, that's where it comes from.  But "chef de cuisine" is the head of the kitchen and not every chef is a "chef de cuisine."  I'm not sure it's so clear to a French person if you go around calling every cook a "chef" what you mean.

Answer (score 8):

***petite*** in English is used as an adjective for a woman or girl that is both short and slender.

> *Kylie Minogue is petite*
>
> *Kylie Minogue est toute [menue](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/menu)* or *Kelly Minogue est un petit bout de femme*.

Whereas *petite* in French is the feminine of [***petit***](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/petit), which can be used both as an adjective and a noun for just about anything that is small (in size, scope, etc.), little, short, young (*les petits*; the little ones), or younger (*petite soeur*; kid sister); (*le petit Dumas*; Young Dumas: the Dumas' son.)

E.g.

> Marie est plus **petite** que Jeanne; *Marie* is shorter than *Jeanne*.
>
> Jean habite une **petite** ville du Loir-et-Cher *Jean* lives in a small town in the Loir-et-Cher.
>
> Saint-Cirq-Lapopie est un joli **petit** village du Lot; Saint-Cirq-Lapopie is a quaint little village in the Lot area.
>
> Tu vois **la petite** la-bas? C'est ma soeur; Can you see the short woman/gal (*also*, young little girl) over there? She's my sister.
>
> Je prendrai **la petite**; I'll go with the small/short one.

Comment: That's more of a case of the word losing meanings in English.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting case is how [*chaise longue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaise_longue) has long since evolved into *chaise lounge* in some usage in the US.

Comment: That one's still the wrong side of the border between 'common error' and 'common usage'!

Comment: Yes, the spelling *chaise lounge* will probably be regarded as a (perhaps common) error, but in the United States it is widely accepted, even among people who are knowledgeable about such matters, to shorten *chaise longue* to simply *chaise*, which, of course, in French means simply a chair (of any kid).

Answer (score 4):

A couple words from western USA/Canada, left over from early exploration days:

**[plew](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plew)** - a beaver skin

Dictionaries claim it to be from the French **pelu** (hairy), but in mountain man/history buff circles it's often claimed to be from the French **plus** (more)

**[parfleche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parfleche)** - dry rawhide, or a container made from rawhide. In reality, it's not literally rawhide. It's slightly worked, but not tanned.

from the French **parrer  flèche** i.e. deflect arrows

**[capote](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capote)** - a coat (historically, a hooded coat made from a wool blanket)

Comment: side note: in french, capote now means condom.

Comment: re [_capote_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/capote): ...as well as many other things, including the coat, and the thing you raise on a convertible car...

Answer (score 3):

'Connoisseur' is interesting because it is 'fake' in two ways; the modern French spelling is *connaisseur*, and the French word refers to knowledge rather than appreciation.

Comment: connaisseur refers to appreciation as well, despite the root *connaissance* meaning knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

In French *prune* and *raisin* refer to plums and grapes in their natural state; in English they refer to the dried variety.

I suppose this is because in the old days it was the only way of preserving them for export.

Also there's *sacre bleu* and *zut alors*, both expressions of annoyance that nobody actually uses.

Answer (score 2):

Something that crossed my mind is "Omelette du fromage". I don't know if it is used by English speaking people but I do know it is a well known phrase among some people. From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Omelette+du+fromage):

> The amazing phrase from Dexter's laboratory in the episode "The Big
>   Cheese", when he listens to a French recording overnight to learn said
>   language. This consequentially gets stuck on repeat, on this phrase.
>   The next day all he can say is "omelette du fromage", actually working
>   to his advantage in everything he does (except at the end, when his
>   lab blows up).
>
> Although meant to depict "cheese omelette", this phrase is
>   grammatically incorrect. You should say "omelette au fromage", which
>   means "an omelette with cheese".
>
> Despite this, people still say the phrase "for the lols."

Comment: That's odd. I wonder if Dexter's "omelette du fromage" comes from Steve Martin? In the 70s, his stand-up act included a routine about 'getting by' in Paris ["... then, this is really dumb, you try adopting a French accent: I waahn to guh to zee hotel" . Then he moves on to ordering a cheese omelette.

Comment: @ David: "Yeah, gimme a shoe with cheese on it, and I wanna massage your grandmother"

Comment: You got it, @DSKekaha!

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Coup de grace is sometimes used to mean Mow de lawn. Campers often have En tent Cordial. Fixez les brakes seems to have superseded Reparer les freins

Answer (score 2):

I think the term you are looking for is [**false friend**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend), or in French, *faux-ami*.

> False friends are words in two languages (or letters in two
>   alphabets)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) that look or sound similar, but differ significantly in
>   meaning. An example is the English embarrassed and the Spanish
>   embarazada (which means pregnant), or the word sensible, which means
>   reasonable in English, but sensitive in French and Spanish.

Some examples I can think off the top of my head:

Chef - anyone who cooks professionally in English, a boss in French

Ancien(t) - Something that is old in English, but in French, *ancien* can also mean "the ex-".

Bras - Plural of brassieres in English, the arms in French

Money/monnaie - Any form of negotiable currency in English, loose change in French.

Library/Librarie - A place where you borrow books in English, a place where you buy them in French.

Comment: A _chef_ in Fr. is broader (all sorts of _chiefs of_), but it is possible to use _chef_ (as an absolute) for the _chef de cuisine_ (_head chef_). I'm uncertain about _sous-chef_ though...

Comment: False friends aren’t necessarily directly etymologically related though, whereas OP, I think, is looking for such a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Would "petty" count? Or has it been part of English so long that it has become an English word?

Comment: Sure, that's a pretty good one -- https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/petit (see #3) can also mean mediocre in French, but that's not quite the same as petty in English

Answer (score 2):

Another answer for this list question (linked to [this recent Q)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613768/36710):

[Un slip](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/slip) in French is [underwear](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip) but of the men's underpants, pants, briefs kind. Mostly a word used for men's clothing (c.f. *protège-slip* for pantyliner).  Though it started as sportswear in the early 20th century, the word *slip* soon became understood as underwear in 1913 written up in:

> la revue L’Illustration pour désigner « une culotte ou un caleçon très court ».

[A slip in English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_(clothing)) is also underwear but for women's clothing, a thin layer often rayon or silk worn under a skirt or dress.    A slip can be skirt length or dress length, "half" or "full" slip with a shorter hem length than whatever skirt or dress is worn with it.

Etymology for [slip](https://www.etymonline.com/word/slip#etymonline_v_23680):

> slip (n.1)
> "long, narrow, and more or less rectangular piece," mid-15c., originally "edge of a garment;" by 1550s generally as "narrow strip;" probably from Middle Low German or Middle Dutch slippe "cut, slit," which might be related to Old English toslifan "to split, cleave."

Women's underwear in French now includes primarily [une culotte](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culotte_(v%C3%AAtement)), another loan word, as much clothing is. Before *slip*, *culotte* was a men's article of clothing, now used moreover for women's underwear in French.   [Culottes](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/culottes) are not the same thing in English:

> women's trousers, usually knee-length or calf-length, cut full to resemble a skirt

Etymology from *[cul](https://www.etymonline.com/word/culottes#etymonline_v_29176)* or bottom.

> from Latin culus "bottom, backside, fundament," from PIE *kuh-lo- "backside, rear" (source also of Old Irish cul "back," Welsh cil "corner, angle"), ultimate origin obscure [de Vaan].

Comment: [Related](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9840/38).

Comment: @tchrist Exato, but missing the Latin and PIE there.  All points to the same, good language link.  *Hiney* for the diminuitive en anglais?

Comment: Thinking of how some Italian pronunciation of casa is [h] and not [k].

Answer (score 1):

And "cul-de-sac". French call a dead-end street "impasse".

Comment: The québécois use cul-de-sac.  But perhaps they got it from the anglophone canadians instead of the french.

Comment: "Un cul-de-sac" is the same as "une impasse" in french. I could use either.

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cul-de-sac is used essentially the same way in French as in English

Comment: "Cul de sac" has the same meaning in French, but it's mildly familiar, so it wouldn't be used on road signs or in documents (at least in France).

Comment: What's funny about this one is it seems the word meaning has changed so much in english we expect a turnaround bulb on one now, where as dead-end or impasse would mean a stub without a bulb.

Comment: @Joshua: "We" is a tricky word. Your expectations may not match other people's.

Comment: Fair enough. Before internet I've not seen a contrary though.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang  Uses of the word cul-de sac in French are recorded long before the Old Continent decided to set foot across the Pond! See the TLF, [etymology](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/cul-de-sac) and [uses](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cul-de-sac). Nowadays French people prefer *voie sans issue* to cul-de-sac and this might be a consequence of *voie sans issue*  being the term used by the highway code. An ngram shows the decline of the use of the word in French in the 20th century. Too long to include the result of an ngram in a comment but anyone interested can run it themselves.

Comment: @Laure - I think the issue - as hinted at by Bruno - is that 'cul' is mildy rude or at least 'mildy familiar' so the language moved away from the expression cul-de-sac

Comment: @tom As a French native and considering as well the authoritative link I've pointed too I can assure you this is absolutely not an issue. In France (I wouldn't know about Quebec or other French speaking areas) it is just slightly old-fashioned.

Comment: @Laure - ok fair enough you must be correct - but french colleagues almost seemed embarrased when I mentioned cul-de-sac ... perhaps they were just amused or confused. --- from another point of view I remember BCBG had a formal meaning of bon chic bon genre, but was also referred to as bon cul belle gueule, which also seemed to embarass people - but I would be interested to know if this is mildly rude or just more 'familiar'  - thanks for your helpful comment

Comment: This is a set expression from [1307](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/20/1515), and only from the late 17th did the concrete meaning for the word _cul_ started to be marked as vulgar. In _cul-de-sac_, it stands for the bottom of an object, there is no reference to _ass_ here whatsoever. On road signs in [Québec](http://www.rsr.mtq.gouv.qc.ca/Dispositifs/Details.aspx?cid=13020&che=INDCT-INFRM&cat=INFRM&) (it should not be used as the generic for an [odonym](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1199872); also see sign note). Just usual to me. Generally, see _Laure_'s comments.

Answer (score 1):

In [Eurovision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_at_the_Eurovision_Song_Contest) "nul points" or "nil points" are made-up expressions meaning zero points:

> When a country finishes with a score of zero, it is often referred to
>   in English-language media as nul points, or sometimes nil points. The
>   correct French for "no points" is pas de points or zéro point, but
>   none of these phrases is used in the contest, as no-point scores are
>   not announced by the presenters.

"Douze points" is also used, meaning the maximum 12 points one country can give another, but that is [genuine French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17387/is-douze-points-genuine-french).

Answer (score 0):

My all time fave is "Voulez vous coucher avec moi ce soir?"

Oh wait.  What's that?  You say that actually does mean, "Do you want to...?"  My bad.

Comment: Good one! The Wiki entry says it is used in _The Streetcar Named Desire_: I'm having a problem finding it. Oh, and +1, naturally, to balance out the downvote, among other things. People are so petty.

Answer (score 0):

I would posit that in US English, **[Fillet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fillet)** qualifies as a *Fake French* word, merely due to how most people I have known from the US pronounce it (fɪl·eɪ rather than fɪl.ɪt).

Answer (score -2):

Of course.

For instance, the word ***partez*** is sometimes used (jocosely and otherwise) to mean party (the noun *or* verb).

***Count de Monet*** is how a stingy person is sometimes referred to (to their face).

I recently made an attempt on ELU to introduce ***payage*** (for tollage). A long and intriguing discussion ensued.

***Toot sweet*** is more or less ubiquitous.

There is plenty of French-like nonsense, mostly parodied, in the English and American literature. One example that springs to mind is Charlotte's "***departez!***" (she means to say "depart!") in Nabokov's *Lolita*. The same novel mentions our especial fondness of ***Ball Zack***.

(Needless to say we're also fond of ***Bow Mar Shay***, ***Flaw Bear***, ***Due Mar***, and constantly ***Parley Voo*** about various stuff going on in the province of ***Sham Pain***).

Generally, it is the belief of all people worth speaking of that every educated person must speak English no matter where he was born; but every educated person who also thinks of himself/herself as intelligent must also speak French. It is, after all, the language of the cultured class. I'm almost not joking.

There's a cafe just north of ***the Plus Maw Bare*** in Paris where my painting of ***the Shut Lay*** hangs. In case you're wondering what this Plus Maw Bare is, here's my painting of it:

[image]

P.S. On @SevenSidedDie's request: t To those who don't get it (for whatever reason):

1. **Partez** (pronounced par-TAY) is what some people think, or pretend to think, is the French word for "party". As in "Let's party!"
2. **Count de Monet**: *Comte* is the French word for "Count," but this is ignored by the joker. "Count the money" is the implication here.
3. Payage means "toll" in French. "Tollage" means "toll" in English. "Fundage" means money secured for a project (the project can be anything, including, but hardly limited to, buying food and paying rent).
4. **Toot sweet**: a phonetic rendering of *toute de suite*. Means "right away" in French. Toot: to make a short, high sound with a horn or whistle. Sweet: being or inducing one of the basic four (some say six) taste sensations.
5. **Departez!** - means exactly nothing in French. But it does *look* a lot like the English verb "depart". Assumptions are sometimes - a bit cavalierly, perhaps, which makes them funny.
6. **Ball Zack**: phonetic rendering (a little bent to fit American pronunciation) of the name Balzac (as in Honore de Balzac, famous French novelist and coffee lover).
7. **Bow Mar Shay**: Pierre Beaumarchais, French dramatist and dissident.
8. **Flaw Bear**: Gustave Flaubert, French novelist.
9. **Due Mar**: Alexandre Dumas, Pere and Alexandre Dumas, Fils, father and son, French novelists and dramatists.
10. **Parley Voo**: from "Parlez-vous Français?" ("Do you speak any French, you moron?"); here: just "talk" or "speak". The "vous" part makes it sound sophisticated (in some people's opinion).
11. **Sham Pain**: Champagne, of course.
12. **The Plus Maw Bare**: Place Maubert.
13. **The Shut Lay**: Place de Chatelet.
14. ***Lolita***: here, a novel by Vladimir Nabokov, in which, among other things, a middle-class housewife writes a love letter to a man whom she is trying to impress by using what she thinks is a French word.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Toot sweet = "tout de suite" is idiomatic and correct French.

Comment: So is "parlez-vous" as in "parlez-vous français?"

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, but Frun Say is usually dropped, and what's left stands for plain old "talk."

Comment: @sumelic - "toot sweet and the tooter the sweeter" is, of course, based on tout-de-suite, but with the 'tooter the sweeter' added - I think this was slang from WWI with English troops in France, but I can't remember other examples.....

Comment: Toll = [_Péage_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/p%C3%A9age/58848?q=p%C3%A9age#58491) i.e. right to pass on foot (lat. pes, pedis) not _payage_ (sic).

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax: Dude, lighten up.

Comment: Bro, don't mislead the native speaker about the phonetics, spelling, and semantics of the French language, especially not all at once. Oh, and please, keep your images to a tasteful size. Thanks.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax: Maybe you should re-read the question, tiger.

Answer (score -2):

Of course there exist words as described and they are called **loanwords**.

From the [British Library](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/changlang/activities/lang/twentieth/loanwords.html), we have:

"*Loanwords are words brought into one country from another. Words are generally 'loaned' when two different cultures come into contact with each other. This might be because of immigration, trade, fashions or foods, travellers tales, the arts (paintings, books, poetry or film), technologies, wars or colonisation*".

Complementing this thought we have in the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/loanword) that loanword is "*a word adopted from a foreign language with little or no modification*".

[**HERE**](http://www.english-for-students.com/French-Loan-Words.html) is a list of French loanwords used in English, among them, some very well-known: *bidet*, *camouflage*, *coup d’etat*, *croissant*,
*cuisine*, *lingerie*, *prestige*, *silhouette*, *souvenir* and *voyeur*.

In portuguese (my native language), they are known as "estrangeirismo" (foreigness if literally translated). In German and French they are known as "xenisme" with a slight difference in French because of the acute (xénisme).

Comment: A downvote for nothing. Thank you, community! That's very constructive.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think I know the reason for it. I'm not a French speaker, but I believe the terms you listed are used in French as well,  whereas for example *douche* or *bon ton*  means something quite different in English compared to its original meaning. I'm not sure if *bon ton* is actually used in French, maybe it is. Boh!

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Bon ton* is definitely French. @ Eduardo Not my downvote either but the one you got is likely pointing the fact you missed what the question is about. It is not about words coming from French in English as, according to the Oxford Dictionary definition (little or no modification), there are likely thousands and may be tens of thousands of these, but about loanwords with meanings that have substantially diverged between French and English. None of the ones you cite are in this case.