# Are there examples of mutual loanwords in French and in English?

Tags: loanwords, french

I was once asked the question:

> What French word is commonly used in English for which an English word is commonly used in French?

The answer was respectively *rendezvous* and *date*, which I found very unsatisfying.

So, does such a situation exist, in which a French loanword is used in English to mean something for which an English loanword is used in French?

**Criteria**:

- Both loanwords should be fairly common in the language that borrow them. By that, I mean that it is expected of the general population to know this word. A more precise definition of this criterion would be the absence of the "specialised" tag in [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/).
- Both words should ideally be actual loanwords, meaning that their spelling hasn't changed, except for any punctuation. ("Gastronomy" or "beef" wouldn't count.)

**Research done**:

I've looked at [various lists of French words](https://blog.busuu.com/french-words-in-english/) used in English and did not find a match, as well as [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300015/are-there-any-fake-french-words-used-in-english). ChatGPT was no help.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149260/discussion-on-question-by-mat-are-there-examples-of-mutual-loanwords-in-french-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*From comment:*

As I once commented on [an earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389226/use-of-the-word-buffet), quoting from a cross-Channel ferry announcement,

> "Ladies and gentleman, the *buffet* is now open. Mesdames et messieurs, le *snack-bar* est maintenant ouvert."

I have also seen *savoir-faire* in a spoken English sentence subtitled in French as *know-how*.

My guess is that the first may have been unconscious, while the second may have been a deliberate play on words by the translator.

You (Mat) responded with "I thought *buffet* in that context had the same meaning in French and in English. When it comes to food, *buffet* in French is almost synonymous with *buffet à volonté*, so it’s probably a wise choice to translate it as *snack-bar* (maybe they did so after experiencing having to deal with disgruntled French expecting all-you-can-eat buffets)" and "Another example close to *buffet* could be *diner* (in English) and *snack-bar* (in French). I believe both share the same meaning."

Comment: Note that this use of *buffet* in English is probably a British thing, and tends to be restricted to transport situations.  In many, even most, cases *buffet* (en) would translate better to *buffet à volonté* than to *snack-bar* (fr).

Comment: I suspect it is the equivalent of a train's "[buffet car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffet_car)" (less formal than a dining car, as you purchase food and drink standing at a bar) but on a ship

Comment: I'm sure it is - also "station buffet", which could often be a counter-service cafe, but wasn't always

Comment: Sorry but snack bar and buffet do not work at all.

Comment: @Lambie Can you elaborate a bit further? Maybe simply _bar_ in French, [which also seems to come from English](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/etymologie-bar) would be a better alternative, as it would be the word used in French, including in transport situations. Also, what about _diner_/_snack-bar_? I'm not completely proficient in English.

Comment: I'm half-French and moitié-anglais and I approve this answer.

Comment: buffet in English is a way to serve food; snack-bar in French has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Lambie: doesn't really matter, the words are used to mean the same thing by Ferry operators.

Comment: @PatrickT Ferry operators? Hmm.

Comment: @Lambie: "Buffet: a restaurant in a station, where food and drinks can be bought and eaten" ([dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/buffet)). I guess the usage has been extended from stations to ferries; doesn't seem too much of a stretch!

Comment: @psmears Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 12):

**Garage** (borrowed in English) and **Parking** (borrowed in French) can both refer to a building used for storing cars.

Garage : Etymology :
Borrowed from French garage (“keeping under cover, protection, shelter”), derivative of French garer (“to keep under cover, dock, shunt, guard, keep”)
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garage#Etymology

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thougt about it, but I don’t think they share the same meaning. It would be very odd, [although maybe technically correct](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/garage), to refer to a parking or car park as a "garage" in French. I’m pretty sure it would be the same in English, but I’m not a native speaker.

Comment: @Mat Indeed, "garage" doesn't seem to be used currently in French in this sense. On the railway one finds "voies de garage" which is perhaps the sense in which it was borrowed for car parking.
In American English, "Parking garage" is quite common and seems a likely source of the current French usage.

Comment: @Mat: Underground or multi-level car parks are very often referred to as *garages* in America English. And the underground ones seem to be called [*parkings souterrains*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/parking-souterrain) in French.

Comment: @PeterShor I see, so it’s a very good answer then! _parking_ or _parking sous-terrain_ would indeed be used for underground or multi-level car parks.

Comment: As a French person, I find this the best answer so far. *Un parking* is indeed the standard French word for a car park (including underground or multi-level) and thus a very common word.

Comment: @grahamj42 French _garage_ originally denotes the act of protection, therefore storage, and therefore also of parking a vehicle.  It also by extension denotes a building where one does that, so it is the source of English _garage,_ not derived from it.  (Also note the relationship with _gare,_ railway station.)

Comment: @phoog I meant that *garage* is borrowed from French. I think Mat misunderstood as well. Time for an edit!

Comment: @grahamj42 I got that, I just wasn't sure of its use in English. If possible, a definition or example sentence with a reference of the use of garage as "car park" would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

**Chic** (borrowed from French, German origin)
EN : Stylish and fashionable
FR : Elégant, distingué

**Glamour** (borrowed from English)
EN : Combination of charm and good looks
FR : charme, sensualité, élégance.

Comment: The French use chic, they don't say glamour instead of it.

Comment: The meanings aren't really the same. *Glamour* in French is the kind of ostentatious charm that is associated with magazine covers. It's a lot closer to the English *glamour* than to *chic*.

Answer (score 7):

**Festival** is a word borrowed into English from Old French with no change in spelling and then re-entered French from English. It is like an absolute mutual loanword.

Here is the etymology of *festival* from [*Etymonline*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/festival):

> 1580s, "a festal day, appointed day of festive celebration," short for *festival day* (late 14c.), from Old French *festival* (adj.) "suitable for a feast; solemn, magnificent, joyful, happy," and directly from Medieval Latin *festivalis* "of a church holiday," from *festum* "festival, holiday," neuter of *festus* "of a feast" (see feast (n.)). **The English word returned to French 19c. in certain specialized senses.**

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possibility, although not really a very good one.

In English, [*roué*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=roue) means

> A man who recklessly indulges in sensual pleasures; a rake.

And in French, [*lovelace*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lovelace) means

> Séducteur, généralement libertin et peu scrupuleux.
> Seduceer, generally libertine and unscrupulous.

The French word is derived from the character of Robert Lovelace in Samuel Richardson's novel *CLarisa*.

Unfortunately, I don't believe *lovelace* is a common word in French.
(But it's not vanished completely: [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lovelace%3Afre_2019%2Crou%C3%A9%3Aeng_2019%2C+roue%3Aeng_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, lovelace isn't exactly common (I never heard it before). Also it seems to come from a surname, so I don't think it qualifies as an English word. (For instance "Don Juan" as in "C'est un Don Juan" isn't considered a Spanish phrase.)

Comment: It is extremely uncommon. The two literary examples given in the TLFI date back to the 19th c.

Comment: @Mat: I have to disagree; it is indeed an English word. The OED has the definition **Lovelace**: *a seducer, a libertine,* and has citations from 1773 and 1998. Unfortunately, it seems to be even less common in English than in French (where it seems to mainly have fallen into disuse after the 19th century, although [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lovelace) has a few 20th century citations).

Comment: I even tried Langue Sauce Piquante, les correcteurs du Monde and could not find it.  It would seem to be the most likely place to find it: Désolé, mais rien ne correspond à votre recherche. Veuillez réessayer avec des mots différents. https://www.lemonde.fr/blog/correcteurs/?s=lovelace

Comment: @PeterShor Well, the fact that, as you said, it’s even less common in English than in French, that it is sometimes spelled [with a capital "L"](https://www.littre.org/definition/lovelace), and that [most dictionaries indicate its origin as coming from Richardson’s novel](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lovelace) (and not from English) seem to suggest the opposite.

Although, Richardson apparently also used it as an English word, and made up the name from two other English words. Some [sources (Tardel, H.)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lovelace) also state it was taken that from English.

Comment: So we can consider it was taken from English. My main issue with it is how uncommon it has become these days. But otherwise it fits the criteria pretty well!

Comment: @Mat many words come from names. Off the top of my head, [_sideburns_](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sideburns#etymonline_v_23488), [_Kafkaesque_](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Kafkaesque#etymonline_v_1763), [_svengali_](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Svengali#etymonline_v_22447), [_Dickensian_](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Dickensian#etymonline_v_53931), and I am sure there are many more, these are just the ones I could remember now.

Comment: @terdon Obviously. My point was that the word in French was probably directly taken from the book, rather than from English which took it from the book. It can be hard to differentiate admittedly.

Comment: @PeterShor "CLarissa" -> "Clarissa", thanks

Comment: To add to the rarity of _lovelace_ in French, _roué_ is also pretty uncommon in English. I recognised the word and knew it’s meaning, but I can’t say I can recall ever hearing or seeing it used anywhere. If you’d asked me to list words meaning ‘rake’, I doubt I would have been able to pull _roué_ from whatever dark recesses of my mind it inhabited.

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding loanwords in two languages are difficult to find. One example of adjacent loanwords is the following:

English: *[maillot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maillot)*

French: *le [pull[-over]](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=3492773505;r=1;nat=;sol=0;)*, *le [bikini](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bikini)*

So the English *maillot* can refer to a few garments, as Merriam-Webster indicates. Two of the garments are a swimsuit (usually a one-piece women's suit) and a jersey. Most image or product searches for *maillot* yield a swimsuit, as seen in these Google image results:

[image]

At least historically, *maillot* could also refer to a jersey, as some [Oxford English Dictionary quotes](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/maillot_n?tab=meaning_and_use) attest:

> 1948    At a gala evening where the men would discard their maillots for starched linen. A. Waugh, Unclouded Summer iv. 65
>
> 1948    His heart was thudding against the cotton of his maillot. A. Waugh, Unclouded Summer iv. 78,
>
> 1955    In a not quite clean maillot and a seersucker skirt. D. Barton, Glorious Life vi. 74

French has at least two non-exact loanwords from English.

The French *le bikini* is derived from the Anglo-American *Bikini* (itself from a German name for the atoll, in turn from the Marshallese Pikinni [[Wikipedia, Bikini Atoll]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikini_Atoll)), which was the name of the atoll where the US Navy carried out atomic bomb tests. Fashion designer Louis Reard borrowed the word from news reports of the first atomic tests, and the term then quickly spread across the fashion world. In a way, *bikini* in English is thus a double loan-word, lent to French and quickly taken back into English in a different sense.

The term is not quite synonymous with the swimsuit *maillot*. A *maillot* is almost always one-piece. A bikini is two piece.

[image]

As for *le pull* or *le pullover*, it refers specifically to something like this:

[image]

It's hard to say whether this compares to the once-used jersey sense of *maillot*. Two possibilities are that the *maillot* was really a [traditional jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jersey_(AM_2005.58.3).jpg), in which case it's very close to *le pull*:

[image]

and that it was closer to a [modern sports jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey_(clothing)#/media/File:WTOS_Delft_cycling_jersey_(cropped).jpg), which would make it not so close:

[image]

Comment: *Un sweat* is right up there with *un pull* but not a sweater or sweat.  Clothing loan words, c'est la fête du slip !

Comment: "bikini" is a French word. Not loaned from English.

Comment: For bikini, It is apparently German -> English -> French -> English. Or something: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pikinni#Marshallese

Comment: maillot may be found on some English sites for swimsuit but it is just snobbery; no one actually uses it.  In any case, it is a one-piece [swimsuit].

Comment: It's difficult to make sweeping statements: There are regional and age differences. I've heard my English grandmother say "maillot" and she was not snobbish.